# Conjunctions between complex clauses - which items do they coordinate?

Tags: syntax, cross-linguistic, conjunctions

In a sentence like:

*He had joined up for no other reason than to escape, [blank] hated army life.*

I would use the conjunction *and*. In the equivalent Thai sentence, though, it seems that native speakers would use *but*.

For me, the first clause makes clear that he didn't really want to join up in the first place, and there's no opposition between that and hating army life.

At the same time, that clause does state that he joined up, and if you focus on that then there is the same opposition as there would be in *he joined up but hated it*.

I should mention that the sentence is in a context where it's definitely not news that the guy in question had joined the army, and isn't really news that he joined up because he felt he had to, not because he really wanted to.

How can I express this difference in more linguistic terms? Can I say that EN looks at the pragmatic meaning of the complex clause as a whole, whereas TH looks at the proposition that appears highest in its structure tree?

Are there other examples of this kind of difference, possibly between (other) European languages and other Asian languages?

Comment: Logical connectives are semes and morphemes can be polysemic. So, a morpheme, as a conjunction, can correspond to several logical connectives. Thus, your morpheme in Thai can mean "but" and "and" depending on the context. Or English "and" can have a versative meaning instead.

Comment: An article in the same vein: Explaining additive, adversative and contrast marking in Russian and English.... https://www.researchgate.net/publication/242074822_Explaining_additive_adversative_and_contrast_marking_in_Russian_and_English

Comment: An *and* wouldn't work well here, because it could seem to add to *for no other reason*. Then it could mean that, while he hated army life, it was still better than what he had escaped from. Whereas a *but* would negate that. That obviously depends on context. Although, if it's a new sentence contrasting with *he joined*, as you say, it's a new sentence and doesn't need a connective, practically leaving the context open for further clarification. I don't know Thai; I'd expect the difference comes down to usage, not syntax. In your first sentences, a comma or fullstop before *in* matters a lot.

Comment: [continued] The comma or difference would appear in sound only as intonation and rythm (stress). Likewise so for your example.

Comment: "and yet" would be quite good or "yet he".

Answer (score -1):

*and* does not work well here, because.

You cannot transpose the sentence without potentially changing the meaning: *He had joined and hated army live for no other reason ...*; Unless that's exactly what you are trying to say. It doesn't work in principle, if transposed, because the tenses aren't in agreement (*he had hated army live*?). That's not usually a problem, and not directly the question. One could assume that *and* binds the whole preceding sentence. Then we might transpose: *He hated army live, and he had joined for no other reason than ...*. That works, but it's still slightly ambiguous whether *he joined for no other reason*.

> Can I say that EN looks at the pragmatic meaning of the complex clause as a whole

You could say that *and* does not add to the meaning (or gives a sense that is unlikely) and is simply ignored. The sentence thus remains *underspecified*.

Your reluctance to use *but* may stem from the assumption that it would be redundant, because the meaning is strongly implicit already from your personal context. You still concede that it's not explicit, but merely not contradicted ("there's no opposition between that and hating army life").

Compare also "Monday is the worst (of all) weekday(s)". Small morphemes are frequently redundant and ignored.

I'd say there is no notable difference at all.

Edit:

I just ran across *I'm no mathematician, **but** I didn't understand the quantum mechanics talk*. Of course there's no contradiction between a mathematical and a quantum mechanical understanding. The author seems to imply that mathematics were not a strict prerequisite for such a talk, contradicting but the lecturer, who seems to think otherwise.

Comment: Of course *and* works (in fact I agree with the OP that it's the natural choice). The coordination is between (a) *had joined up for no other reason than to escape* and (b) *hated army life*.

Comment: @TKR I took a slightly less strict approach in my other comment to the question, so I tend to agree to the extend that the ambiguity is not irritating. However, as I say, the "and" doesn't do any notable **work**. Do you disagree?

Comment: Well, it does the syntactic work of coordination... What other work could it be expected to do?

Comment: @TKR if "*and*" coordinates both clauses what does it coordinate them to? Well, it keeps the context open, but that's not the same as "but", which terminates the context early. If "*joined*" relates to "*army live*", then that's https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-serial_dependencies and interesting.

Comment: I think you may be misparsing the sentence -- *joined up* doesn't take *army life* as its object, nor does *escape*; there are two independent clauses coordinated with *and*. A paraphrase is *He had joined up for no other reason than to escape; he hated army life.*

Comment: @TKR What did he join (join up, to be precise), if not the army? How would one know that, if army life wasn't mentioned?

Comment: *Join up* is intransitive. You can *join the army*, or you can *join up*, but you can't *join up the army*.

Comment: @TKR a) how did I understand the sentence, although I am not familiar with this idiom? By MW it is not all that specific anyhow c) as I wrote, small particles are ignored, like "up"; the issue would remain the same without it, wouldn't it? d) what is an up and how can I join it?

Comment: *He had joined up for no other reason than to escape* is a complete grammatical sentence, and *He joined up the army* is ungrammatical. Are you disagreeing with either of these statements? If so, there's not much I can do beyond suggesting you consult other native speakers of English.

Comment: @TKR I'd agree with the first, insofar complete doesn't preclude underspecified. I wouldn't know how to argue against the second. There's nothing about "join up" that prohibits transitivity other than redundancy with "join". I'm afraid high-level native speaker intuition might occlude underlying mechanisms. It's unlikely to learn join up in an environment where the military (or whatever else) is never mentioned, for one.

Comment: @TKR re your 1st comment I would say there are 3 propositions a) he joined up b) his reason for joining up was purely to escape c) he doesn't like army life. It seems that the EN speaker looks for something that coordinates b) and c) and plumps for *and*, whereas the TH speaker looks for something that coordinates a) and c), and plumps for *but*. Would you agree that, on a pragmatic level, b) is the gist of the first clause, whereas a) would appear higher in its structure tree? If so, how can I test whether this captures what is going on (TH latching onto grammatical saliency, EN pragmatic)?

Comment: @Minty I think you'd want to look at a lot more data on the usage of the Thai and English conjunctions. It's very hard to generalize from one data point.

Comment: @vectory In *I'm no mathematician, but I didn't understand the quantum mechanics talk*, the *but* is signalling that the speaker had hoped or expected to understand the talk despite not being much of a mathematician. IOW it is signalling a contrast between expectation and outcome, as in my original sentence. Your example requires a bit more real world knowledge to relate the expectation to the statement and derive something like *I'm no mathematician, so maybe I shouldn't be surprised, but I didn't understand the talk on quantum mechanics*, but it's essentially the same.

Comment: @TKR yes absolutely, but I am struggling to come up with more test sentences. I can perhaps reverse the order in the original so that the not really wanting to join up is highest in the structure tree, as well as being the gist, but am finding it hard to come up with other complex conjuncts. I don't think the equivalent of *joined up for no other reason than to escape* can contain a conjunction, but it must contain two ideas which generate opposite expectations when taken in isolation. Every example I have come up with is a rehash of the original, i.e. doing something for an ulterior purpose.

Comment: @TKR that's the big question. I think it depends on your theory of syntax, but there are many theories. I do not actually know what *context* means in any of those, for what it's worth. As above, ambiguity is inherent. Especially if "and" can handle contrast like "but". Minty: yes, sure, especially if the "... but I didn't understand the talk" can contrast with the a preceding sentence like "I went to see a quantum mechanics talk" (that I omitted here). Still though, the wider context of the article, and your use of "maybe" allows for another "maybe it could be better without the mathematics".